# How to use HTML Templates in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some html templates, i want use it in rails app. I copy all css and js file to rails app folder but how to include it in view? I'm new in ruby on rails, everytime learning always use bootstrap and scss file.

Comment: Instead of posting this question here, why didn't you find some tutorial about rails? Rails has [great documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).

Comment: Read the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) on layouts and page rendering. That page will answer all your questions and give you an understanding of how Rails works. If the documentation doesn't make sense, then try the [Getting Started Tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just copy css files in `app/asses/stylesheets`, js files in `app/assets/javascripts` and place all the images in `assets/images` folder.
And change the images path from your views templates and css file.

Answer (score -1):

This link will help you to solve the issue

http://drnicwilliams.com/2009/10/06/install-any-html-themetemplate-into-your-rails-app/